# Play test GearVR game on dev computer

Tags: testing, unity-game-engine, oculus, unreal-engine4

How can I play test my GearVR game on my development computer without building and running on my phone?

I'm looking for either an answer for a game built with either Unreal Engine or a Unity3D.

Comment: you can run the game using Unity3D's Game window... Window->Game... once you click the play button you should be able to see your game... you really don't need to have the phone at the beginning...

Comment: Saeid, I'm able to do this but then don't have mouse/keyboard control over the player. I'm thinking of adding a standard Player Controller prefab in addition to the OVR Player Controller prefab so that I can switch between them by toggling them on/off when I'm developing / building for the Gear VR. Does that seem reasonable? I don't know if that kind of approach is compatible with the Unity game loop, but will try it and report back.

Comment: @MichaelHogan Hello. You seem to be new here. Your question didn't quite meet  our standards - please take a tour around the site (available when logged of) and check out the help center to find out what do we expect from questions. I edited your question to be a bit more understandable, those changes will be applied once peer reviewed. I also tried to write an answer, I hope it will be helpful. If you reply to someone in your comments, make a @ mark before their nick, just as I did - otherwise, they wont be notified about your reply.

Comment: @K.L. Thanks for the tip on using the @. I wrongly assumed a commenter gets subscribed.

Comment: @MichaelHogan yes, in fact even I use OVRPlayerController + gravity=0 for testing... and once I am done I probably switch it back to the OVRCameraRig(aka OVRCamerController)...

Answer (score 2):

**Dont playtest without a headset**

"Playtesting" on a PC completely misses the point of playtesting in it's regular meaning.

Playtesting VR apps is important, and has to be performed with a headset. One of the biggest challenges of designing VR games is ensuring a comfortable (not nauseating) experience and percise, intuitive input/controls. If you run your app on a PC with the WSAD/mouse duo, your playtest will be pretty much worthless.

**Cheap alternative**

Google cardboard is the cheapest option, if you have a decent smartphone. The experience wont be as good as when using Gear VR, but it will be a lot closer the real thing than using a PC. It will let you test actual gameplay as intended.

**If you really need mouselook**

I found that testing some features (not gameplay itself!) is a lot faster if I cut out deploying to a device from the workflow, so I actually implemented what you ask for.

I dont have Unity at hand right now, but it is quite easy to do. In a initialization script you can check if you are running on Gear VR or a PC, and enable the appropriate control script. it could look like this:

```
void Start() {
    #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
    setAndroidCameraRig();
    #endif
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    setEditorCameraRig ();
    #endif
}
```

Your `SetEditorCameraRig` could look something like this:

```
    pcRotateHead pcHead = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<pcRotateHead> ();
    pcHead.enabled = true;
```

Where `pcRotateHead` is a script that updates it's object orientation each frame based on mouse movement:

```
public class pcRotateHead : MonoBehaviour {
  public float XSensitivity = 5f;
  public float YSensitivity = 5f;

  public void Update()
  {
    float yRot = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * XSensitivity;
    float xRot = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * YSensitivity;
    Vector3 baseRotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    Vector3 newRotation = new Vector3(-xRot + baseRotation.x, yRot + baseRotation.y, baseRotation.z);
    Quaternion newQuatRotation = Quaternion.Euler (newRotation);
    transform.rotation = newQuatRotation;
  }
}
```

Check out the Unity manual: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

Comment: "Playtest" may have been poor word choice. I am testing with headsets for exactly the factors you mention: comfortable and smooth head movement, controls while in VR. I'm collaborating with another developer and we're sharing a GearVR so my ultimate goal is being able to make a little progress when it's not my turn to use the headset. I'm hoping to take advantage of being able to press the play button inside of the Unity editor so that I can do a basic check to make sure changes to the level seem to be what I want before taking the additional step of building and running on my GearVR.

Comment: Your answer seems helpful. I'll give it a try and see how it goes. Thank you for posting.