# Testing on a gearVR

Tags: unity-game-engine, gear-vr

I am building my first VR game for the Gear VR(Since I got it for free). The question I have is there a way I can plug in the GearVR and run it on unity that way I can see what is going on in the game, while the game is being played? Currently the way I am testing my game is by building it, transferring it to my phone, installing it, then testing it. Which is very tedious. Here is my setup in case it helps:

unity 5.5

Android Studio

Oculus Mobile SDK

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082825/play-test-gearvr-game-on-dev-computer

Answer (score 1):

Unity should be able to load the code and profile it without you manually installing. If you follow the [instructions from oculus](https://developer3.oculus.com/documentation/game-engines/latest/concepts/unity-build-android/) all you need to do is check the box for "Development Build" and "Autoconnect profiler"

[image]

You also may want to [enable Developer Mode](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/oculus-browser/latest/concepts/browser-remote-debugging/) on the phone so the app can be run without it being in the vr headset.

Comment: 2nd link doesn't work. how to debug only with the phone instead connecting it with the headset everytime?

Comment: @TouhidulIslam I have updated the link, it is under the section "Enabling Gear VR Developer Mode" on that page

Comment: Thanks a lot. it really helped. I was just going crazy swapping phone inside the vr and out